# Fourier transform and dual vector space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory

In Serre's *A Course In Arithmetic*, it says the following:

[image]

I don't know what it is talking about, I know the definition of $f'$, but what is **This is** in the last sentence refered to? $f'$ is a function on $V$, not $V'$. So what is such rapid decreasing function $g$ that have domain on $V'$?

BTW, it would be helpful if someone can also explained such measure $\mu$ is $invariant$ by what function?

Comment: I can't tell by your post.  Are you aware that $f'$ is not the derivative of $f$? (unfortunate choice of notation.  More common these days is $\hat f$)

Comment: Yes, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This definition is a little fast-paced and can be easily misunderstood. Here, $y\in V'$ so that $f'$ is indeed defined on $V'$. The way you can see this is the dual pairing in the exponent of $e$: $\langle x,y\rangle$ implicitly tells you that $y$ is in the dual space where $x$ comes from. Hence the "this is" that you refer to is actually $f'$ as defined on $V'$.

As for what invariance means, it is likely that it means invariant under translations, i.e. $\mu(E+x) = \mu(E)$ for any Borel set $E$ in $V$ and $x\in V$. This is key to the really nice algebraic structure of the Fourier transform.